# Binary Tree - Random Generator

Tags: java, algorithm, random, data-structures, binary-tree

Suppose I have a Binary tree like this -

```
       5               
      / \       
     /   \      
    /     \     
   /       \    
   2       8       
  / \     / \   
 /   \   /   \  
 1   3   6   9   
      \   \   \ 
      4   11   10
```

Now I have a random generator which will generate a number between 1 to size of tree (10 in this case). Based on the random value generated by the random generator I have to return the node from the tree(Suppose, generator given 7, so I return the 7th node(value 11), doing inorder traversal). Tomorrow I add 4 more nodes to the tree. How do I maintain the consistency? As in, the same node from the tree is returned for the random value. The inorder traversal will create a different array and the value of the index will change.

Comment: Inorder traversal is how I approached but that does not stay consistent once I add more nodes.

Comment: What does consistency mean here? In the example tree, if the random number is 7 then it returns the 7th element, which is 7 (lots of 7s!) If tomorrow you insert values 0, 3.5, 11, and 14, do you _still_ want to return 7 if the random number is 7? Or do you want to return the 7th number in the in-order traversal (which would now be 5). (Note that inorder traversal will always generate the elements in sorted order.)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a valid binary search tree?  If it is, 11 is in the wrong place.

Comment: No its just any binary tree. The tree here looks like BST but the question is for binary tree.

Answer (score 5):

Your question doesn't really make sense unless your goal is to construct a binary tree by adding nodes to it, and *freezing the mapping between indexes and nodes at a certain point*, so that *future* additions to the tree (after the freezing point) don't change that mapping.

It still isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish, but I can see a couple possibilities.  If your intent is that new nodes can be added anywhere in the tree, then they really can't have any indexes that map to them sensibly.  In that case, I would just create a map (e.g. a `HashMap`) at the freezing point, to map the indexes to the nodes.  Traverse the tree with an in-order traversal, build the map, and save it together with the tree structure.  Use the map to determine the node for an index, rather than traversing the tree.

If, instead of adding nodes anywhere in the tree, you want to add nodes in a place so that the original nodes will still have the same index, then all you need to do is go down the tree's right children until you hit a node with no right child.  In your posted example, that would be the node `10`:

```
       5               
      / \       
     /   \      
    /     \     
   /       \    
   2       8       
  / \     / \   
 /   \   /   \  
 1   3   6   9   
      \   \   \ 
      4   11   10**
```

Mark that node at the point where you want to freeze.  Then, when you add a new node, the new node must be added as either the right child of the marked node--or if the marked node has a right child *R* (since you've already added one after freezing), anywhere where it will be a descendant of *R*.  New nodes added in this way will always succeed, in an in-order traversal, the nodes that were present at the freezing point.  Thus the indexes of the previously added nodes won't be affected.

If neither of these is what you want, you will need to provide more clarification about what you need.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to just add any new nodes as right children of the last node in the in-order traversal. This will lead to a very deep and unbalanced tree; you didn't ask for a balanced tree, so it's possible that that's OK.